# Excel Lookup Formula Needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a worksheet, similar to the one in this image;

[image]

I need a formula that will search the 'Make' and 'Color' columns in the table and if one of the pairs of values matches a pair in the outside list, the corresponding 'License Plate #' value will be added to the outside list. Essentially I'm looking for something along the lines of IF 'Nissan' exists in column O AND the value in column P next to it equals 'Red', THEN cell Q5 will equal the contents of cell N4 or 'PRT-2417'.

Comment: What happens if there's more than one Green Chevy?

Comment: The actual data that I'm using is patient names and ID numbers so both sets are all unique instances that only appear once.

Comment: Got it. Well done. You might add that to the question; the fact that the data pairs are known to be unique is relevant.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue can be solved by using `Index` and `Match` combination.**

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming that you have Source data in Range 
  `A2:C6`(excluding header).
- Enter Target data in Range `E1:F6` (including 
  header).
- Enter this Array (CSE) Formula in cell `D2`, 
  finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$6,MATCH(1,(F2=B$2:B$6)*(G2=C$2:C$6),0)),"No Match")}
  ```

**Let me explain mechanism behind the Formula.**

Generally, an `INDEX` & `MATCH` formula configured with `MATCH` set to look through a one column range and provide a match based on given criteria, without concatenate values in a helper column, or in the Formula itself.

But the shown Formula works around this limitation by using boolean logic to create an Array of `1` & `0` to represent rows matching to `2 criteria`, then using `MATCH` to match the first `1` found.

The temporary Array of `1s` & `0s` is generated with this combination.

`(F2=B$2:B$6)*(G2=C$2:C$6)`

Returns,,

`{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE}* 
 {FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE}`

Finally makes,,

`MATCH(1,{0;0;1;0;1}`

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*